# How to compute for an average with specific date range in TIBCO Spotfire?

Tags: spotfire, spotfire-analyst

I have a data table (1 month data) opened in TIBCO spotfire, I have Date, User ID and defect rate columns.
I want to have a calculated columns which, it will only average the defect rate of the last 15 days from the date now.

Can someone help me to write the calculated columns formula?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a data limiting expression in a visual

[Date] >= dateadd('dd',-15,DateTimeNow())

For a calculated column is the it in a sum if statement

Sum(if( [Date] <= dateadd('dd',-15,DateTimeNow()), 1,null))